# Norm estimates if adjoints can't be computed

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics

Assume that you have two linear maps $A$ and $V$. For a given $x$ (of appropriate dimension) you can compute $Ax$ numerically, and for any $y$ (of appropriate dimension) you can calculate $V^Ty$ numerically. But you do not have access to both $A^Ty$ and $Vx$ on your computer. Hence, you can compute things like $$\langle Ax,y\rangle\quad\text{and}\quad \langle x,V^Ty\rangle$$
and you may even be able to estimate
$$\sup_{x,y}|\langle Ax,y\rangle -  \langle x,V^Ty\rangle|.$$

My question is:

#### Is there a way to reliably compute $\|A-V\|$? (Any norm would be fine, spectral norm desirable. An upper bound would also be ok.)

I'd like to add, that this situation is somehow always the case in floating point arithmetic, because each time you compute `A*x` or `A'*y`, different rounding errors occur, hence the results of `(A*x)'*y` and `(x')*(A'*y)` are different, too. (Btw, does anybody know an estimate for this quantity?) In double precision, this is probably not much of a problem, but in single or half precision, the errors seem to become non-neglectable.

Comment: Have you looked into randomized numerical linear algebra? If I understood correctly, the issue is that you can never take the full supremum in your estimate, and not even for all in a "nice" subspace for which you have approximation properties? That seems like a similar situation to me.

Comment: Sounds natural - do you have a specific entry point in mind?

Comment: A natural starting point would be https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/randomized-algorithms-in-numerical-linear-algebra/41CF2151FADE7757AA95C7FC15E43630, and there's also https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04481 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01387. You could also specifically look at a randomized SVD, which you could compute for $A-V$ based on what you have and should give you (an estimate of) the spectral norm.

Comment: Thanks! Will look! An SVD of $A-V$ seems hard to if can't apply neither $A^T$ nor $V$...

Comment: Oh, you need to combine it with an iterative scheme such as the Golub-Kahan-Lanczos bidiagonalization. (But maybe you could add a bit of background on your situation where you can compute $\langle Ax,y\rangle$ without computing $Ax$... You don't mention whether your linear mappings are finite- or infinite-dimensional, for example.)

Comment: How big are these matrices?

Comment: I don't have a particular size in mind - would the answer differ for 20x20 and 2000x2000 matrices?

Comment: Dumb suggestion: if you can calculate $Ax$, then you can probably calculate $AX$ ,where $X$ is a matrix. Could you not just numerically calculate $AI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix? This approach seems reasonable if the matrix is only 20x20.

Comment: Sure, these case are fine in double precision! But if you go to half precision, you'll get quite different results for `(A*x)'*y` and `x'*(A'*y)` even in this size.